# redirect location after execution is wrong

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have been mulling over this for hours, to the point of myopia looking at this screen and I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

I can a script which redirects to a unique page (defined in variables) after execution. The script works fine but the location it redirects to is wrong every time.

For example. A user has 4 links to check, lets say they are new comments on his/her page. When he/she clicks the link it directs to the oldest one every time. Not the one they clicked on.

I have 2 parts of code:

```
<?
$result_s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pins a LEFT JOIN comments b ON a.id = b.pin_id WHERE b.to_id = '$myid' AND b.status = '0' ORDER BY date DESC");  
$rows = array();
while ($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result_s)) { 
  $jS = '"'.$row[id].'"'; 
  $boardid = $row['board_id']; // collection id
  $postid = $row['pin_id']; // post id
  $posturl = $row['pin_url']; // post id
  echo "<table width='100%'><tr>";
  echo "<td align='center'><a href='javascript:setActive(".$jS.")'><img src='".$posturl."' height='100'><br>".$boardid."/".$postid."</a></td>";
  echo "</tr></table>";
} 
?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function setActive(ObjID)  {  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  
    else {  
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }   
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {  
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {  
        //Return Value. Handle as you wish. Display or ignore.  
        var x = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        if (document.getElementById(ObjID).style.color == 'black') document.getElementById(ObjID).style.color='red';
        else document.getElementById(ObjID).style.color='black';
        document.getElementById(ObjID).innerHTML = '<center><font face="Century Gothic">' + x + '</font></center>'; 
      }  
    }  
    var p_str = "a="+ObjID; 
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/application/views/setActive.php",true);  
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    xmlhttp.send(p_str); 
    location.href="/board/pins/<?php echo $boardid; ?>/<?php echo $postid; ?>";
  }  
  </script>
```

I have tried using different variables in the location part of the script but nothing works. I'm not educated in this so maybe I'm missing something that is glaringly obvious to some programmers out there, which is my reason for asking here.

Can you see what the problem might be?

Comment: You have to change the href inside the part where your ajax returns. But doing so makes it unnecessary to do anything else there. If you want the user to see the change and then change href, you need to use setTimeout(function() { location = '...'; },3000) for example

Comment: you mean request $boardid and $postid in setActive.php, overwriting the location in the script?

Comment: I don't want the user to see it, it should be seemless

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues

1. The A in Ajax stands for asynchronous. So whatever you do right after the .send is executed BEFORE the Ajax call (The use of XMLHttpRequest is called Ajax)
2. You call the function with an ObjID which is then acted upon in the RETURN of the Ajax call (whatever is inside the  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange) but not known in there since ObjID is not global and not copied to the scope (closure)

Try this

```
function setActive(ObjID)  {  
  var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
      new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
  var ID = ObjID
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(id) {
    return function() {
      if (this.readyState != 4) return;
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id); // id is passed now
        var style = obj.style; // but please use CSS intead
        style.color = style.color == 'black'?'red':'black';
        style.fontFamily = "Century Gothic";
        style.textAlign="center"; 
        obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        setTimeout(function() { 
          location.href="/board/pins/<?php echo $boardid; ?>/<?php echo $postid; ?>"
          },3000); // assuming this is what you want
      };
    }(ID); // passing the ObjID
  }
  var p_str = "a="+ObjID; 
  xmlhttp.open("POST","/application/views/setActive.php",true);  
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
  xmlhttp.send(p_str); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this reworking does not allow a click at all. Clicking does nothing.